aliases for azure custom policy
what is the supported aliases under provider 'Microsoft.Sql' and resource type 'servers/databases' to create an azure policy to audit pitr and ltr
i tried the below
{
  "properties": {
    "displayName": "Meijer PITR & LTR for SQL DB",
    "policyType": "Custom",
    "mode": "Indexed",
    "description": "Audit the SQL databases in POC for correct PITR and backup settings",
    "metadata": {
      "category": "SQL"
    },
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "parameters": {
      "pitrRetentionDays": {
        "type": "String",
        "metadata": {
          "displayName": "PITR retention",
          "description": "The number of days to retain the point-in-time recovery."
        },
        "defaultValue": "15 days"
      },
      "differentialRetentionHours": {
        "type": "String",
        "metadata": {
          "displayName": "Differential backup frequency",
          "description": "The number of hours to retain backups with 12-hour differentials."
        },
        "defaultValue": "12 hours"
      },
      "weeklyBackupWeeks": {
        "type": "String",
        "metadata": {
          "displayName": "Weekly LTR",
          "description": "The number of weeks to retain weekly backups."
        },
        "defaultValue": "3 weeks"
      }
    },
    "policyRule": {
      "if": {
        "allOf": [
          {
            "field": "type",
            "equals": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases"
          },
          {
            "field": "type",
            "equals": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases/backupLongTermRetentionPolicy"
          },
          {
            "anyOf": [
              {
                "field": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases/restorePointInTime",
                "notEquals": "[parameters('pitrRetentionDays')]"
              },
              {
                "field": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases/backupLongTermRetentionPolicy/dailyRetention",
                "notEquals": "[parameters('differentialRetentionHours')]"
              },
              {
                "field": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases/backupLongTermRetentionPolicy/weeklyRetention",
                "notEquals": "[parameters('weeklyBackupWeeks')]"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      "then": {
        "effect": "audit"
      }
    },
    "versions": [
      "1.0.0"
    ]
  }
}




Do you get an error message when you deploy this policy?


what is the supported aliases under provider ‘Microsoft.Sql’ and resource type ‘servers/databases’ to create an azure policy to audit pitr and ltr.

Here are the supported resource types for Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases to create an Azure policy to audit PITR and LTR.

The resource field type dailyRetention is not available in the backupLongTermRetentionPolicy resource type.
Policy Error:

You can use backupShortTermRetentionPolicies instead of backupLongTermRetentionPolicy with the above-supported types.
Here is the updated policy to audit PITR and Ltr.
    {
      "mode": "Indexed",
      "policyRule": {
        "if": {
          "allOf": [
            {
              "field": "type",
              "equals": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases/backupShortTermRetentionPolicies"
            },
            {
              "anyOf": [
                {
                  "field": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases/restorePointInTime",
                  "notEquals": "[parameters('pitrRetentionDays')]"
                },
                {
                  "field": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases/backupShortTermRetentionPolicies/retentionDays",
                  "notEquals": "[parameters('rentalDays')]"
                },
                {
                  "field": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases/backupShortTermRetentionPolicies/default.diffBackupIntervalInHours",
                  "notEquals": "[parameters('internalInHours')]"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        "then": {
          "effect": "audit"
        }
      },
      "parameters": {
        "rentalDays": {
          "type": "String",
          "metadata": {
            "displayName": "PITR retention",
            "description": "The number of days to retain the point-in-time recovery."
          },
          "defaultValue": "15 days"
        },
        "pitrRetentionDays": {
          "type": "String",
          "metadata": {
            "displayName": "PITR retention",
            "description": "The number of days to retain the point-in-time recovery."
          },
          "defaultValue": "30 days"
        },
        "internalInHours": {
          "type": "String",
          "metadata": {
            "displayName": "Weekly LTR",
            "description": "The number of weeks to retain weekly backups."
          },
          "defaultValue": "12 hours"
        }
      }
    }


The policy was successfully created and assigned with the required parameters.

Reference: How to audit SQL DB with PITR retention period
